# SQL Query on nullable columns

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL

```
select * 
from posts 
where expiry_date is > GETDATE()
```

`expiry_date` is a nullable `datetime` column. Basically I want retrieve all posts where they have not expired but also all posts where `expiry_date` is null.

How do I achieve this? Do I need an OR condition?

Comment: `select * from posts where expiry_date is > GETDATE() OR expiry_date is NULL`? Depends on SQL dialect, probably. Can you tag accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Below is for SQL Server:

> Do I need an OR condition?

Answer: Yes

You also have a syntax error, which I fixed:

```
select * from posts where expiry_date > GETDATE() OR expiry_date IS NULL
```

Comment: Is this standard across DBMSs?

Comment: @Dani Mathew, the query above is for SQL Server. GETDATE() function is RDBMS specific meaning that the name and behaviour of the function is different between different database engines, e.g. MySQL uses "NOW()" which is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of SQL have NULL-safe operators.  However the most general method is an explicit test:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where p.expiry_date > GETDATE() pr p.expiry_date is null;
```

You could also do this using `coalesce()`:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where coalesce(p.expiry_date, getdate() + 1) > GETDATE() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE expiry_date > GETDATE() OR expiry_date is NULL
```

On SQL Server.